# File "does not exist" error message when trying to knit

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am getting an error message that one of the files I have loaded doesn't exist, however, I have been knitting the document constantly and this issue hasn't come up until now and I don't believe I have done anything different to cause this to happen.

Here are some photos:

[image]

[image]

I have checked my file and it definitely does exist, so I am not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Likely due to spaces in your folder names.

Comment: Try to include the absolute path to your file

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: I've never come across `here::here()` before. Looks handy but I'd imagine it could fail sometimes. As Wael suggested, try using absolute (complete) file paths, like `/path/to/my/files/athletics-results.csv`.

Comment: If you type out the full name that's given in the error message, i.e. use `read_csv("/Users/tillyfarrell/.../athletics-results.csv")` (with the ... filled in properly), does it give the same message?  What if you replace `read_csv` with `file.exists`?  I'd guess there's a typo in the last part of the name:  maybe the hyphen is a long dash or some other character.

Comment: I'm just confused why the error message is only coming up now because I've been knitting constantly and it's been working, and I haven't changed anything with the files at all

Comment: You may have changed your working directory, for example by starting a new session, or called `here::i_am()` in the wrong place. Try running the same code with absolute file paths without the calls to `here()`. If you really want to use `here()`,  take a look at the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/here/versions/1.0.1/topics/here) for how `here()` searches for files and make sure your directories are arranged accordingly.